# Uwp execute backgroundtask at user login

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task

I'm learning win10 uwp and my goal is to perform an operation, like updating a tile, when the user logs in.

I've checked on msdn and it seems that a BackgroundTask is what i need. So I followed the instructions to create and register a background task found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299100.aspx and on related pages.

```
BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder= new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
taskBuilder.Name = "TaskClassName";
taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = "TaskNameSpace.TaskClassName";

// set conditions (execute when user become present)
taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.SessionConnected, false));
taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.UserPresent, false));

   var registration= taskBuilder.Register();
```

Namespace and class of my `BackgroundTask` are placed in a separated project under the same solution and added in Declaration tab of Package.appxmanifest with property `System Event` selected.

My `IBackgroundTask` implementation is

```
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        UpdateMyTile();

        deferral.Complete();
    }
```

When debugging with visual studio the code run correclty and update the tiles so I think my issue is on how I registered the task and not in the task implementation.

To be sure I've added a second `BackgroundTask` to existing project which is called on timer basis every 15 minutes and that executes the same functions. In this second case the background task is registered and executes as expected.

```
BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilderT= new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
taskBuilderT.Name = "TaskClassNameTimer";
taskBuilderT.TaskEntryPoint = "TaskNameSpace.TaskClassNameTimer";

taskBuilderT.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));

var registration= taskBuilderT.Register();
```

I've also tried using only one `SystemTrigger` first with `UserPresent` and then with `SessionConnected` without success.

**Update 27/01/2016**

@Jakie: no I didn't use `BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();` because on https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtriggertype.aspx for SessionConnected and UserPresent says

> Windows 10, Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview, and Windows 10 Mobile:  You do not need to place an app on the lock screen before the app can successfully register background tasks using this trigger type.

<del>I'm going to try it to see if this changes current behaviour.</del>
I've added call to `BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();`, using windows 10 no dialog has been displayed but it has returned `AllowedMayUseActiveRealTimeConnectivity` but task was not called at login after a restart.

I've started diagnostic log and found the events relative to my background task, it's properly registered but then it gets canceled. Event reports says eventID 19 Task 100. I don't know where to search information on the meaning of these codes, any suggestion?

Comment: Can you check the background task logs in the Application Event logs? see to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299101.aspx

Comment: Also, did you do await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync(); before register the background task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to updated succesfully a tile on user login. In addition to operations already described in my question I've moved the method for task registration to the same project in which background task class is declared.

I've created a class containing a registration method called `BackgroundRegistration`, the class needs to be `sealed`. I've declared the registration method as `static` but this is not strictly necessary.

I've also had success in running my background task at startup user login only when all methods called inside `IBackgroundTask run` method implementation were included in project with background task and classes used were `sealed`. In all other cases I found that my background task was always returning error 0x80010008 which in MS-ERREF is described as:

> The caller (client) disappeared while the callee (server) was
>   processing a call.

Comment: How do find out what was your background task returning?

Comment: @alekkowalczyk using Event Viewer of windows -> Windows Logs -> Application and searching for eventes related to my application. Or better, having a look at all the events marked as error in the log.