# Run background task at startup

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I'm trying to run my background task when I log in into my device right after turning it on. Right now it only runs when I was already logged and I log back in.

I can see that the task is registered perfectly while debugging, still don't know why it doesn't work at startup yet.

```
async void RequestBackgroundAccess()
{
    BackgroundAccessStatus backgroundStatus = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

    if (backgroundStatus != BackgroundAccessStatus.Denied && backgroundStatus != BackgroundAccessStatus.Unspecified)
    {
        RegisterBackgroundThread();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("[Background Access] Denied.");
    }
}

void RegisterBackgroundThread()
{
    var taskRegistered = false;
    var exampleTaskName = "Bot";

    foreach (var bgTask in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
    {
        if (bgTask.Value.Name == exampleTaskName)
        {
            taskRegistered = true;
            Debug.WriteLine("[Background Task] Registered.");
            break;
        }
    }

    if (taskRegistered == false)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("[Background Task] Registering...");

        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

        builder.Name = exampleTaskName;
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = "Tasks.Bot";
        builder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.UserPresent, false));

        BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
        Debug.WriteLine("[Background Task] Registered.");
    }
}
```

Bot.cs

```
namespace Tasks
{
    public sealed class Bot : IBackgroundTask
    {
        BackgroundTaskDeferral serviceDeferral;

        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            this.serviceDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
            ToastNotification("Starting...");
        }

        void ToastNotification(String message)
        {
            XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);

            XmlNodeList stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            stringElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(message));

            ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add a condition to your task builder, do you get the same result?
`builder.AddCondition(new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.SessionConnected));`

Comment: @Chase Nope, doesn't work either :(

Comment: Just checking: Is `Tasks.Bot` the fully qualified name of your task hosting the background process?

Comment: @Chase yup, it is. Works perfectly when I log back in. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, just two more little things to confirm. 1) Are you invoking your `RequestBackgroundAccess()` method before `RegisterBackgroundThread()`? 2) Is your `Tasks.Bot` class sealed?

Comment: @Chase I'm calling BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync() and wait for a response, if it's granted I call the RegisterBackgroundTask method. Yes, it's sealed.

Comment: Ah, yes; didn't catch that. Okay then, the code above seems fine to me, so my guess is the problem is elsewhere. Can you please add to your post the code for `Tasks.Bot`, as well as the code that is invoking `RequestBackgroundAccess()`?

Comment: @Chase I added the code of Tasks.Bot to the question, it isn't full but there're toast notifications to know when it's working. RequestBackgroundAccess() is called after Windows.Current.Activate(). I can see that the task is registered on the console.

Comment: What version of Windows are you testing this on?

Comment: @Chase Windows 10 Desktop, latest update.

Comment: Try setting your system trigger to `SystemTriggerType.SessionConnected` instead of `SystemTriggerType.UserPresent`. `UserPresent` is not as reliable for detecting a login event as `SessionConnected` is.

Comment: @Chase I was using SystemTriggerType.SessionConnected before but didn't work. I tried UserPresent (which people use as startup event too) and it didn't work either, also tried to add SessionConnected as condition to it. Still only works when I log in with the device on already.

Comment: I'm stumped. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. :(

Comment: @Chase thanks for the help, bro! I'm trying to unregister the task and register it again. I did so by re-installing the app but I'm just trying \_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this question.. I believe it's so related to yours:

[Uwp execute backgroundtask at user login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024842/uwp-execute-backgroundtask-at-user-login)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that's same thing that happens to me. Yesterday I unregistered the background task and registered it again, it solved the issue! No code changes.

Comment: I'm glad that your problem solved, if you see my answer is 100% accurate answer, please accept it :)

Comment: This doesn't really provide an answer to the question, just a link to another question. When you post an answer, post the answer here with a link to the source to make it easier for others.

Answer (score 1):

I unregistered the background task and registered it again, it solved the issue that I was having.